# How to send a email using php from local host

Tags: php, email

Hi I need to send email using php. But when I am trying to send a simple email,it is not being sent.What could be the reason? Should I include any header or any permissions?Please help me.
Here is my code.

```
<?php
$to='jyothi.jish@gmail.com';
$message='hai';
mail($to, 'My Subject', $message);
?>
```

Even this small message is not being sent.Can anyone guess what could be the reason?

Comment: which server you are using xampp aur wamp

Answer (score 0):

Well the issue in you need to define mail sending parameters in your server. Such as the mail host, ports etc. The best would be to use http://phpmailer.worxware.com/. You can use the third party such as gmail to send mails for you through your localhost development environment.

You can use

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->Host       = "mail.example.com"; // SMTP server example
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Port       = 25;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "username"; // SMTP account username example
$mail->Password   = "password";        // SMTP account password example
```

to define the connection parameters.

Comment: Community did not allow link only answer 
`http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info`

Comment: PHP mailer script is an apt one for your requirement :)

Answer (score -1):

This is how you can send emails from XAMPP or WAMP (localhost) in PHP in Windows.

```
a) Open the "php.ini". For XAMPP,it is located in C:\XAMPP\php\php.ini. Find out if you are using WAMPP server.
Note : Make a backup of php.ini file

b) Search [mail function] in the php.ini file.

You can find like below.
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost

Change the localhost to the smtp server name of your ISP. No need to change the smtp_port. Leave it as 25.
Change sendmail_from from postmaster@localhost to your domain email address which will be used as from address..

So , it will become like this.
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = smtp.planetghost.com
smtp_port = 25
; For Win32 only.
sendmail_from = info@planetghost.com

c) Restart the XAMPP or WAMP(apache server) so that changes will start working.

d) Now try to send the mail using the mail() function .
```

Comment: hi but when i enquired i came about to know that from localhost i can't send mail

Comment: sorry to disturb you..and thank you so much for your help

Comment: I can't understand your first comment . Can you please elaborate it again.thanks

Comment: You can also use smtp of gmail as describde by "Ela Buwa". See my another answer (Not tested yet)

Comment: @user2934937: If my answer helped you or either ela buwa's answer helped you . don't forget to upvote and accept the answer this will also help another user to find the correct answer when they face same problem . Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
Gmail SMTP server settings for sending mail through Gmail from any email program:

Gmail SMTP server address: smtp.gmail.com
Gmail SMTP user name: Your full Gmail address (e.g. example@gmail.com)
Gmail SMTP password: Your Gmail password
Gmail SMTP port: 465
Gmail SMTP TLS/SSL required: yes
```

This will provide you facility to send mail using smtp via gmail(But i can not test it yet so you can try it and check it if its work for you).